# Remote access to Cloud 9

Tags: ssh, ftp, cloud9-ide

Is there a way to remotely access and edit project on Cloud9 (c9.io) using FTP, SSH?

I know we can access another server via FTP using c9.io but can we access c9.io using a similar way?

Right now I'm doing is pushing the code to github and pulling it back to cloud9 wich is a painful task to do over and over again.

A way to directly access it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this looks promising: [http://superuser.com/questions/858193/how-can-i-ssh-into-my-cloud-9-workspace](http://superuser.com/questions/858193/how-can-i-ssh-into-my-cloud-9-workspace)

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet possible. We do have SSH support on the roadmap.

Comment: Yes it is possible!  http://superuser.com/questions/858193/how-can-i-ssh-into-my-cloud-9-workspace follow the link. I have tried and succeed.